# PuTTY sending extra garbage before each Telnet command

Tags: terminal, putty, telnet

I'm trying to establish a Telnet connection to my 3d printer with PuTTY. It connects, but when I send a command I get `echo:unknown command` followed by the correct command I tried to send, in the correct format. Looking at the printer terminal it appears to be receiving a bunch of additional characters before the command that I'm sending

[image: putty terminal next to printer terminal from separate webhost]

How do I get rid of the `"ÿûÿû ÿûÿû'ÿýÿûÿý`?

Comment: Your printer evidently isn''t supporting telnet, which uses octet FF (which in single-byte codes like 8859-1 and Windows 1252 is assigned to ÿ small-y-diaresis) for "Interpret As Command". **Try putty's Connection Type "Raw"** instead of "Telnet".

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 so that should be an answer, not a comment, cuz it worked. thank you!